# setState into store component

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I have to set a value on from a API into a newly created `<button>` component handled by Redux, but I don't know if I can use setState for this. I created a reducer and an action SET_VOTE_COUNT but I'm not seeing how this is done. This is my first Redux project, so here is the code:

```
// ./src/js/components/CounterList.js
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { increment, decrement } from '../actions/reducer';
import Counter from './Counter';
const CounterList = ({
  counters,
  onIncrement,
  onDecrement
}) => (
  <ul>
    {counters.map(counter => 
      <Counter style={{div: "voting"}}
        key={counter.id}
        value={counter.count}
        onIncrement={() => onIncrement(counter.id)}
        onDecrement={() => onDecrement(counter.id)}
      />
    )}
  </ul>
);
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    counters: state
  };
};
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    onIncrement: (id) => dispatch(increment(id)),
    onDecrement: (id) => dispatch(decrement(id))
  };
};
export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(CounterList);
```

---

// ./src/js/components/Counter.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
class Counter extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
        <div className="voting">
            <span>{this.props.value}</span>
            <button
            onClick={() => this.props.onIncrement()}>
            +
            </button>
            <button
            onClick={() => this.props.onDecrement()}>
            -
            </button>
        </div>
        );
    }
}
export default Counter;
```

---

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import logo from '../../logo.svg';
import '../../App.css';
import AddButton from './AddButton'

class Posts extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            response: ''
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        fetch(
            "/posts"
        ).then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => this.setState({ response: data }))
    }

    render() {

        return (
        <div className="App">
            <header className="App-header">
            <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />

            {Array.isArray(this.state.response) &&
                this.state.response.map(resIndex => <>

                    { resIndex.voteScore}

                    <AddButton className="voting"/>
                    <p> { resIndex.title }, by { resIndex.author } </p>
                    <p> { resIndex.body } </p>
                    <p> {resIndex.category} </p>
                </>
            )}

            </header>
        </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Posts;
```

---

```
import React from 'react';
import { add_counter, setVoteCount } from '../actions/reducer';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

const AddButton = ({dispatch}) => (
  <div className="voting">
    <button
    onClick={() => {
      dispatch(setVoteCount())
      // dispatch(add_counter());
    }}>
      Vote
    </button>
  </div>
);

export default connect()(AddButton);
```

---

The reducer:

```
// ./src/js/actions/counters.js
export const setVoteCount = (id) => {
    return {
        type: "SET_VOTE_COUNT",
        id
    };
}
export const increment = (id) => {
    return {
        type: "INCREMENT",
        id
    };
};
export const decrement = (id) => {
    return {
        type: "DECREMENT",
        id
    };
};
export const add_counter = () => {
    return {
        type: "ADD_COUNTER"
    };
};
```

---

store action:

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux';
const composeEnhancers = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose;

const change_counter = (state = {}, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {

        case "SET_VOTE_COUNT":
        if (state.id !== action.id) {
            return state;
        }
        return {
                ...state,
                count : 37
        }
        case "INCREMENT":
        if (state.id !== action.id) {
            return state;
        }
        return {
            ...state,
            count: state.count+1
        };
        case "DECREMENT":
        if (state.id !== action.id) {
            return state;
        }

        return {
            ...state,
            count: state.count - 1
        };
        default:
        return state;
    }
};
let nextId = 0;
const counters = (state = [], action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
    case "ADD_COUNTER":
        return [...state, {id: nextId++, count: 0}];
    case "SET_VOTE_COUNT":
            return [...state, {id: nextId++, count: action.count}];
    case "INCREMENT":
        return state.map(counter => change_counter(counter, action));
    case "DECREMENT":
        return state.map(counter => change_counter(counter, action));
    default:
        return state;
    }
}
export default createStore(counters, composeEnhancers(applyMiddleware()));
```

---

I can upload it to GitHub if necessary. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In the AddButton component,the actions should be wrapped in `mapDispatchToProps` and passed to the connect function.  You are calling the raw action in your example, but you need to wrap it with dispatch for it to update the store.

However, I'm not sure what you are trying to update the store with exactly. The action payload is empty in your example, and the reducer has 37 hardcoded as the state.count in response the SET_VOTE_COUNT action type. Did you mean to pass something from the API response?

```
<AddButton count={resIndex.count} className="voting"/>
```

```
import React from 'react';
import { add_counter, setVoteCount } from '../actions/reducer';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

const mapDispatchToProps = {
  setVoteCount
};

const AddButton = props => (
  <div className="voting">
    <button onClick={() => {
      props.setVoteCount(props.count);
    }}>
      Vote
    </button>
  </div>
);

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(AddButton);
```

Comment: Yes. Thanks for the tip. I tried to hardcode the number 37 but that didn't work. Yes I mean to pass redIndex.count into the store. I think you need to update the answer so I can accept as correct.

Comment: Thanks for updating the answer. There is a new error when I click the button: TypeError: dispatch is not a function
onClick
src/js/components/AddButton.js:13

Comment: You do not need to call dispatch within the onClick handler if you are using mapDispatchToProps.  You can just call the setVoteCount contained in the props